# Launch Android App from Shorten URL ( Through DeepLink)

Tags: android, deep-linking

There is a perfect way to launch our android application through Deeplink.

```
  <activity
      android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >

    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Here, I can easily launch my application through “http://www.example.com/gizmos”, But my question comes when I am going to hit shorten URL of this link i.e. goo.gl/tNQpWe.

What could be the ways to launch my app through tiny/ shorten url too ? 
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The short url will be redirecting to your server/domain and from there you do the same what "gizmos" did. Deep linking is basically a HTML page rendering some expected data by your android application (In your case android:host and android:pathPrefix)

You will need to create a basic html rendering the android schema if you need data to be passed. I would suggest you to follow Branch.io.

https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-on-android-chrome-intents

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: thanks for the shoutout! The other approach (what Branch does) to this is make the short URL domain itself App Links enabled. Then users hit that domain first and the app opens if installed. If **not**, the user is redirected somewhere else.